# Unable to assign custom policy to IAM users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to give IAM users the ability to use the Policy Simulator, but I get this error when I assign a custom policy. It seems as if it is looking for the policy in the users' profiles? I am the primary admin on the account, so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

[image: error]

I tried creating a custom policy with the necessary actions, but I am not able to assign that policy.

Comment: You are trying to add a policy to an AWS managed permission set, AWS managed permission sets cannot be modified, create a new permission set and add the required policies to this one, then attach it to your group and accounts.

Comment: By the way, are you intentionally using **IAM Identity Center** instead of **IAM**? The names are confusing, but IAM Identity Center is specifically used for Single Sign-On. If you are not using Single Sign-On, then just use the "IAM" console, which is a different to IAM Identity Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @furydrive suggested, I was attempting to add a custom policy to an AWS-managed permission set. I created a custom permission set, and was able to add the policy. I can now use Policy Simulator on roles with that permission set.